# Struggling with responsive design

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I'm struggling with one thing. I'm coding psd to html but when I want to make my site responsive i can't fix problem with one div.

https://codepen.io/Dzonyy/pen/jmjOWV

```css
.features_items {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.features_item {
  padding: 200px 0 100px 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.features_items h3 {
  padding-top: 80px;
  color: #f4d320;
}

.features_item_text {
  padding-top: 15px;
  line-height: 200%;
}

.features_items_person {
  background: url(../images/person.png) top 20% center no-repeat;
}

.features_items_cloud {
  background: url(../images/cloud.png) top 20% center no-repeat;
}

.features_items_database {
  background: url(../images/database.png) top 20% center no-repeat;
}

.features_items_monitoring {
  background: url(../images/screen.png) top 20% center no-repeat;
}

.features_items_person:before,
.features_items_cloud:before,
.features_items_database:before,
.features_items_monitoring:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #8d8d99;
  height: 1px;
  width: 15%;
  top: 48%;
  left: 43%;
}
```

```html
<div class="features_items">
  <figure class="features_item features_items_person">
    <h3>Live Support</h3>
    <figcaption class="features_item_text">This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum.Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="features_item features_items_cloud">
    <h3>Cloud Technology</h3>
    <figcaption class="features_item_text">This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum.Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="features_item features_items_database">
    <h3>Hi Tech Database</h3>
    <figcaption class="features_item_text">This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum.Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="features_item features_items_monitoring">
    <h3>Live Monitoring</h3>
    <figcaption class="features_item_text">This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum.Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

are always in the same lane ?
How to make them in 2 rows with 2 columns at max-width 1024px ?

Comment: Flex container by default is `no-wrap`, just make the container `flex-wrap: wrap` https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Do you want to use Bootstrap or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you change to `row` direction and then make the items wrap `flex-flow: row wrap;`

Additionally you give them a width (`flex-basis`) that is at least 35%, so there can't fit more than 2 in one row.

I updated these 2 rules like below, it will give you 2 columns on wider screens and 1 on smaller.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVozrm)

Stack snippet

```css
.features_items {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;               /*  changed property  */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.features_item {
  flex-basis: 35%;                   /*  added property  */
  padding: 200px 0 100px 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.features_items h3 {
  padding-top: 80px;
  color: #f4d320;
}

.features_item_text {
  padding-top: 15px;
  line-height: 200%;
}

.features_items_person {
  background: url(../images/person.png) top 20% center no-repeat;
}

.features_items_cloud {
  background: url(../images/cloud.png) top 20% center no-repeat;
}

.features_items_database {
  background: url(../images/database.png) top 20% center no-repeat;
}

.features_items_monitoring {
  background: url(../images/screen.png) top 20% center no-repeat;
}

.features_items_person:before,
.features_items_cloud:before,
.features_items_database:before,
.features_items_monitoring:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #8d8d99;
  height: 1px;
  width: 15%;
  top: 48%;
  left: 43%;
}
```

```html
<div class="features_items">
  <figure class="features_item features_items_person">
    <h3>Live Support</h3>
    <figcaption class="features_item_text">This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum.Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="features_item features_items_cloud">
    <h3>Cloud Technology</h3>
    <figcaption class="features_item_text">This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum.Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="features_item features_items_database">
    <h3>Hi Tech Database</h3>
    <figcaption class="features_item_text">This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum.Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="features_item features_items_monitoring">
    <h3>Live Monitoring</h3>
    <figcaption class="features_item_text">This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum.Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: You are a star!

Comment: No problem mate!